# Resizing the vim tabline on NERDTree window resize

Tags: vim

I am using vim (terminal/console vim NOT gui vim) with NERDTree and NERDTreeTabs. 
As you may have guessed I like to use vim's tab functionality to keep track of multiple open files.

I never really liked how the tabs would start at the very "beginning" of the tabline (there would be tabs on top of the NERDTree window). I wanted to have the tabs start from the END of the NERDTree window (i.e. the right edge), resembling an IDE. So I defined my own tabline like so:

```
" Globals
" NERDTree width
let g:ntw = 25

set showtabline=2 " Always show tabs
function! Tabline(width)
    let s = '%#String#'. repeat(' ', a:width).'|'
    for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        let tab = i + 1
        let bufnr = tabpagebuflist(tab)[tabpagewinnr(tab) - 1]
        let bufname = bufname(bufnr)
        let s .= '%' . tab . 'T'
        let s .= (tab == tabpagenr() ? '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#')
        let s .= ' '.(bufname != '' ? fnamemodify(bufname, ':t') : 'New ').' '
        if getbufvar(bufnr, "&mod") " If buf is modified
            let s .= '+ '
        endif
    endfor
    let s .= '%#TabLineFill#'
    return s
endfunction
set tabline=%!Tabline(g:ntw)
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = g:ntw
```

Basically all I am doing is inserting blank spaces into the tabline before any tabs start. The width of the blank spaces would match the width of NERDTree. Now the problem is when I resize the NERDTree window. Obviously, the tab line's extra spacing does not resize itself automatically, resulting in an ugly mismatch.

I was thinking I could find out a way to execute 'set tabline=%!Tabline(g:ntw)" where g:btw is the current width of NERDTree whenever the NERDTree window is resized. But I am unable to find out a way to do this.

As a side note, since I am using NERDTreeTabs plugin, you can assume that the NERDTree window will ALWAYS exist. You can also assume that the NERDTree window will always be on the left.

So then my questions are:

1) Is there a more elegant way of getting this done?

2) If no to 1), how could I achieve what I am trying to do? (example code please)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no `WindowResized` event and Vim's inability to execute asynchronous code makes polling the NERDTree window's relatively hard. You should probably look into one of the plugins/libs that provide async through python. Another solution would be to hook an autocmd on some event that is guaranteed to be triggered often like `CursorMoved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the NERD_Tree window is always at the left, occupying the full height, its window number is 1. You can then query the current width via `winwidth(1)` instead of hard-coding it in your `g:ntw` variable.